# Lavf creates mysterious element in mkv (Matroska) containers with element id BF

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska

Today I noticed that Lavf creates mkv containers that have an element with element id BF and a length of 4 bytes. According to the mkv specs

https://github.com/ietf-wg-cellar/matroska-specification/blob/master/ebml_matroska.xml

element id BF does not exists. What is this? Even if I mux the same input streams with the same settings, this value changes for every file that is created. It is the first child of "Segment information".

Answer (score 0):

About 1 hour later I found the answer myself: This is a CRC32 checksum.

some references:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023979/mkv-seekhead-parsing
https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-lhomme-cellar-matroska-04.html#rfc.section.9.2